# knockout - how to make entire table row clickable

Tags: url, knockout.js, html-table

the first column is clickable and works fine. But now, I'd like to make the entire row clickable based on that same URL. And as each row prints, I'd like each row clickable with that respective URL that is dynamically created.

Sort of like wrapping all the td's for each row within "< a > < /a >"

But not sure how to do ... I saw an example using a databind click in the < tr >. But I'm not sure how to wrap all the tds within that URL, etc.

TIA.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
    <tr>       
            <td style="width: 300px"><h4><a data-bind="text: Name, attr: {href: $root.rootBaseUrl() + 'Items/' + ID}"></a></h4></td>
            <td style="width: 400px"><h4><span>Link this as well</span></h4></td>
            <td style="width: 400px"><h4><span>Link this as well</span></h4></td>         
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: How about `<tr data-bind="click: function() { location.href = $root.rootBaseUrl() + 'Items/' + ID; }">`?

Comment: That is what I was trying to do. Thank you. Hrmm, except it doesn't highlight or get an underline when I hover. Is this something that I need to fix using CSS?

Comment: Yes. You better do it with CSS